# Is BigQuery suitable for frequent updates of partial data?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I'm on GCP, I have a use case where I want to ingest large-volume events streaming from remote machines.
To compose a final event - I need to ingest and "combine" event of type X, with events of types Y and Z.

event type X schema:
SrcPort
ProcessID

event type Y schema:
DstPort
ProcessID

event type Z schema:
ProcessID
ProcessName

I'm currently using Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) to store most of my relational data.
I'm wondering whether I should use BigQuery for this use case, since I'm expecting large volume of these kind of events, and I may have future plans for running analysis on this data.

I'm also wondering about how to model these events.
What I care about is the "JOIN" between these events, So the "JOIN"ed event will be:
SrcPort, SrcProcessID, SrcProcessName, DstPort, DstProcessID, DstProcessName

When the "final event" is complete, I want to publish it to PubSub.

I can create a de-normalized table and just update partially upon event (how is BigQuery doing in terms of update performance?), and then publish to pubsub when complete.

Or, I can store these as raw events in separate "tables", and then JOIN periodically complete events, then publish to pubsub.

I'm not sure how good PostgreSQL is in terms of storing and handling a large volume of events.

The thing that attracted me with BigQuery is the comfort of handling large volume with ease.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this already on Postgres, I advise you should see BigQuery a complementary system to store a duplicate of the data for analyses purposes.

BigQuery offers you different ways to reduce costs and improve query performance:

1. read about Partitioning and Clustering, with this in mind you "scan" only the partitions that you are interested to perform the "event completion".
2. you can use scheduled queries to run MERGE statements periodically to have materialized table (you can schedule this as often as you want)
3. you can use Materialized Views for some of the situations

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery works well with bulk imports and frequent inserts like http logging. Inserting into bigquery with segments of ~100 or ~1000 rows every few seconds works well.

Your idea of creating a final view will definitely help. Storing data in BigQuery is cheaper than processing it so it won't hurt to keep a raw set of your data.

How you model or structure your events is up to you.